# .htaccess redirect dynamic url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` to redirect URLs with particular keywords in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^testa/(.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/testa/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^testb/(.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/testb/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I want to redirect if the URL contains `/testa/` or `/testb/` to a new domain URL:
`https://app.domain2.com/testa/$1` and `https://app.domain2.com/testb/$1` respectively.

I have this URL
`https://app.domain1.com/testa/page/1` which should be redirect to
`https://app.domain2.com/testa/page/1`.

Using above `.htaccess` code I am not getting redirect result. And I want to redirect URL with particular parameter names only and not all URL from domain1 to domain2.

Comment: First of all: _Proper_ problem description please, not "not working." Give an example URL, and explain what happens instead of what you expected to.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^testa/(.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/testa/$1 [R=301,NC]
> RewriteRule ^testb/(.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/testb/$1 [R=301,NC]
> ```

You are missing the `L` (`last`) flag on the two redirects. So processing continues and the last rule ends up rewriting the request to `index.php?/` with a malformed 301 HTTP status - no redirect occurs since the `Location` header is absent.

You need to include the `L` flag on these two rules/redirects in order to trigger the external redirect immediately. ie. `[R=301,NC,L]`.

---

*Aside:*

If you are redirecting to the same URL-path at the target site (eg. `testa` to `testa`) then you might as well capture the entire URL-path, rather than just the part after `testa` (or `testb`). And if it's just `testa` or `testb` then you only need one rule using regex alternation. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(testa|testb)/.* https://app.domain2.com/testa/$0 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.